# Как найти трехзначные числа в множестве и вывести их на печать (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Я только пока что учусь программировать на джаваскрипте, так что не судите строго за возможно глупый ответ:
задача такая: надо найти кубы всех натуральных чисел, состоящие из трех цифр.
написала такой код, но он почему-то не работает. В чем моя ошибка?

```
    var b = new Array ();//складываем числа трехзначные
    for (var i=0; i<11; i++) {
    a = Math.pow(i,3);
    var mass = a.match(/\d/g);
    if (mass.length == 3) {
    b.push(a);                                                                           
    }
    }
    document.write(b)
```

Comment: как именно не работает код? показывает ошибку? ничего не показывает? показывает не правильный ответ?

Comment: я бы сделал a.toString().length == 3, регулярка тут - пушка по воробьям имхо

Comment: Ваша ошибка в том, что _Math.pow_ возвращает число, а у чисел нет метода _match_

Comment: Познай мощь кнопки f12 в браузере, юный падаван

Comment: Ваша ошибка в том, что 0 не является натуральным числом. :)

Comment: Ничего не показывает. Спасибо за комментарии, про падавана очень понравилось ))

Comment: @Елена - сообщения об ошибках выводятся в разделе (закладке) "Console".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

```
var cubes = [];
for (var i = 1; ; i++) {
  var a = Math.pow(i, 3);
  if (a > 999)
    break;
  if (a > 99)
    cubes.push(a);                                                                           
}
console.log(cubes)
```

Comment: Единственный разумный вариант проверки числа на трехзначность. Как вариант `if (a>=100 && a < 1000) cubes.push(a);`

Comment: @andy.37 - Задача, наверное, в разделе на регулярные выражения: "When the only tool you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail."

Comment: Я сама себе задачку придумала, так что можно и без регулярных. Просто недавно написала с регэкспами пересчет с двоичной в десятеричную и там работало. Так что что знала - то писала :) Там тоже числа разбивала на цифры, но с помощью регэкспов

Answer (score 0):

Вроде всё работает норм..

```
var b = new Array ();//складываем числа трехзначные
for (var i=1; i<11; i++) {
    var a = Math.pow(i,3);
    if (a.toString().length == 3) {
        b.push(a);                                                                           
    }
}
console.log(b)
```

Comment: Ставьте тогда сразу `i < 10`, и можно длину не проверять. А еще лучше: `var b = [125, 216, 343, 512, 729]; console.log(b);`

Comment: я думал о последнем варианте, но решил,что от авторского варианта лучше отходить по минимуму

Comment: а что делает console.log? У меня в AceHTML не работает этот код :(

Comment: Уважаемые господа, всем спасибо за комментарии, ошибки поняла, все заработало, вы мне очень помогли